# What can one learn from a plot of calculated molecular orbitals?

Tags: computational-chemistry

What can one learn from the plots of the various iso-probability surfaces/orbitals of a given molecule/system? Can any predictions be made about bonding or kinetics by looking at these plots? Can an absorption spectrum be extracted from it? etc.

(I am aware this is a broad question, and a quick bullet list would suffice)

For example:

> Energy diagram of the molecular orbitals explored for the D6h
>   structure (left) and the D3h distorted geometry (right) ([source](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/C0CP01326A))

[image: Energy diagram of the molecular orbitals explored for the D6h structure (left) and the D3h distorted geometry (right)]

Comment: @Jan this is a general question, and the other one is more particular. I don't think there's much overlap. If you insists, I'd redirect the other one here.